# deduced conflicting types for parameter '_BIter' ('int*' and 'int')

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++17

I was trying to implement a simple reverse array function:

```
void reverse(int (&arr)[], int n)
{
  int start = 0, end = n - 1;

  while (start <= end)
  {
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
  }
}
```

In my main() I have this:

```
int brr[9]{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  cout << brr[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

reverse(brr, 9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  cout << brr[i] << " ";
}
```

How ever I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'reverse(int [9], int)'
65 |   reverse(brr, 9);

no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int [9]' to 'int (&)[]'
12 | void reverse(int (&arr)[], int n)

deduced conflicting types for parameter '_BIter' ('int*' and 'int')
65 |   reverse(brr, 9);
```

I want to know what is this behavior and how to correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function declaration:

```
void reverse(int (&arr)[], int n);
```

the type of `arr` is a reference to an array of unknown bound. However, the argument `brr` is of type `int [9]`, and you cannot bind a reference of an array of unknown bound to an array of known bound.

---

You have several options:

1. You could decay the array to a pointer:

```
void reverse(int *arr, int n);
```

This does mean that you need to pass the size to the function, and you *have to make sure* that you get the size right, otherwise you might invoke undefined behavior.

2. You could make `arr` a reference to an array of 9 ints.

```
void reverse(int (&arr)[9]);
```

Note that `n` is pointless here, since the size is fixed, and so you could just drop the second argument. This does mean that you can also call this function with arrays of size 9.

3. The way I would recommend is to make `reverse` a template, and deduce the size of the array.

```
template<int n>
void reverse(int (&arr)[n]);
```

This has the advantage that `n` can vary, i.e. this works with arrays of any size. Also, you don't need to pass it the size when you call the function, since it gets deduced.

Comment: "a reference to an undimensioned array." Why does that type exist at all? Can I create an array of that type? Is it purely to assist `shared_ptr<T[]>`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's a remnant from C I think, where you can convert from array of unknown bound to an array of known bound, and vice versa, which is not possible in C++. I'm not sure what practical uses it has in C++. Not many, at least. I've edited the explanation to use the right terms as well.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0388r4.html

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You can for example declare an extern array of unknown bound, and define it with known bound elsewhere. Not very commonly useful since global state is evil. Another case is simply to declare functions that accept array but are adjusted to pointer, and you want the declaration to express intent. Both of those are quite C-ish things inherited into C++. Only practically useful C++ case I know is the template specialisation.

Comment: @eerorika That's very interesting. I always thought `void foo(int arr[])` was just a different syntax for `void foo(int* arr)`, but looks like even if I do `using T = int[]; void foo(T arr);`, the argument is still a pointer. That's very strange.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's not quite "different syntax for pointer". `int[]` is always syntax for array of unknown bound. The rule is that if you declare function whose parameter is an array, that parameter is *adjusted* to be a pointer to element. If you were to write `T variable{};` after that typedef, you wouldn't get a pointer, but an error.

Comment: @eerorika oh, that also applies to regular array types like `using T = int[10];`. I was under the impression that `void foo(int arr[N]);` to `void foo(int* arr);` conversion was some syntactic magic and wouldn't work with a type alias. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @T.C. Thanks a lot for that link. It appears that cppreference isn't up to date. It still mentions references to arrays of unknown bound being disallowed as function arguments.